# ElasticSearch query - exists but doesn't contain

Tags: elasticsearch, contains, exists

I'm trying to build a query that will return results only if they contain a certain field BUT only if that fields doesn't equal a specific value.

I can't manage the proper syntax:

```
POST webdata/interaction/_search
{
   "query": {
      "filtered": {
         "filter": {
            "exists": {
               "field": "mediaType"
            },
            "and": {
               "not" {
                   "term" : { "mediaType" : "none" }
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [Bool Filter](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-filter.html) with `must` and `must_not` clauses.

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": {
                        "exists": {
                            "field": "mediaType"
                        }
                    },
                    "must_not": {
                        "term": {
                            "mediaType": "none"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```